# React Native chat (Front-end) with Faye rails (Back-end)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, react-native, chat, messaging, faye

I have rails 4 app which uses Faye for chat messaging. Now i have implemented react native app and want to use same chat feature(backend) with react native, any solution?